# How to make installation stick having storage partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

I'd like to create USB stick having both:
a) Ubuntu 16.04 installer,
b) storage partition.
So I can boot a computer with it, install or just start Ubuntu and be able to copy data from computer drives to the storage part.

"Startup Disc Creator" makes two partitions: first ISO Joliet about 1.5 GB, second FAT32 EFI 25MB, and leaves rest as unused. I tried to create partition there but both Discs and GParted applications complain about sector size error (drive descriptor shows 2048B while Linux says 512B).

I found similar question: "Creating a startup disk on a partition of a USB drive", but a workaround making two primary FAT32 partitions does not work, "Startup Disc Creator" always uses whole drive, writing first 1.5 GB of pendrive and leaves rest unusable (126 GB).

Tried "Install GRUB2 on USB from Ubuntu Linux" too (http://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/), but a command "grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdd" returns "input-output error".

Is there any other way to make one USB stick for both purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I have done few bootable USB keys for Ubuntu with Startup Disc Creator and could always create additional storage space. When you start Startup Disc Creator and select the USB you desire to make bootable, you will see two selectable options on the bottom part of window. Itreads something like:

When starting from this disk, documants will be stored in reserved extra space... (select this option). You can set how much of this extra space you wish to create. Be sure not to select the option bellow that reads:

Discarded on shutdown unless stored elsewhere.

Anyhow, the space on the USB key that is not occupied with OS image and this extra space is still usable for transfering data, as if the USB key would be "normal" USB key (I mean "not bootable"). But if you boot into live sesion from this key and wish to save something, this will be saved in the extra space you have created and not on the unused part.

Comment: I know this question was answered 4 years ago, but there are no additional options on the Startup Disc Creator menu besides the image you want to burn and the usb to mount to. There's no additional options menu or selectable options.

Comment: It seems that this option was removed in 16.04. For example see https://askubuntu.com/questions/778295/where-is-reserved-extra-space-in-startup-disk-creator-16-04. I do not know if there is currently workaround for this.