# Where is reserved extra space in Startup Disk Creator 16.04?

Tags: usb, 16.04, startup, disk, disk-usage

I've recently installed updated my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and one of the resources I most use is the Startup Disk Creator. And one of the problems that I'm having is, I can't install an .ISO at my USB drive and have space for storage, I need to choose between one and another.
Let me show the difference:

Top image is from Ubuntu 14.04 Startup Disk Creator which has Reserve Extra Space option. Bottom image is from Ubuntu 16.04 where the option is missing:

[image]

And more, after installing the system, my drive becomes impossible to format even in the own Linux, not even `gparted` was able to format it, recognizing my 8gb USB drive with a "Libparted Warning":

So if choose Cancel, it shows as a Unallocated file system

If I choose Ignore, it shows many file systems with a size that my USB drive doesnt have

PARTITION PROBLEM:

[image]

So I'm forced to format my USB drive at another computer, I used my Chromebook to format and be able to use it again. I'm willing to downgrade to 14.04, so I don't deal with these kind of bugs anymore. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answering your last question first. The newer live-usb ISO's are hybrids that work for both MBR and GPT systems. `gparted` cannot read these after Startup Disk Creator has burned the ISO to the USB flash drive. Rather than taking your USB to another computer to reformat it you can use `dd` (Data Destroyer, real name Data Duplicator):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1
```

Change `sdX` to `sdd`, `sde`, or whatever your USB drive letter is.

#### *Use `dd` with great caution!*

---

As you discovered Ubuntu 16.04 Startup Disk Creator no longer provides an option for persistence storage for a Live Boot USB Flash Drive. But `mkusb` does provide this feature and it works well even for creating a pre-release Ubuntu 18.04 Live Boot USB.

For more about `mkusb` details read about it [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: 1. The statement about gparted is correct for 16.04 LTS, but gparted in 17.10 and newer versions can identify the ISO 9660  file system; 2. Use dd with great caution, or use [mkusb also to wipe the head end of the drive or to restore it to a standard storage device](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe). mkusb 'wraps a safety belt around `dd`'.

Comment: @sudodus **1.** Like the OP I'm still on **16.04** but it's good to know **17.10** fixes `gparted` because when I eventually upgrade to **18.04 LTS** this inconvenience will be gone. **2.** We both know how wonderful `mkusb` is!